# Default ValueConverter for a binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, default, converters

Is there a way to get WPF to automatically apply a `Converter` to all bindings of a specific type?

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622117/wpf-c-default-valueconverter-for-a-class-in-wpf), but it covers a different case (localisation) and thus has no satisfying answers.

My problem: I've got model classes containing `Commands`, which I would like to bind to WPF Commands. Since the model classes are toolkit-independent, I cannot implement WPF's `ICommand` there. Instead I have a `CommandConverter` which wraps `CommandModel`s into WPF `ICommand`s:

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand, Converter={StaticResource CommandConverter}}" />
```

This works quite well, except that it is easy to forget about the `Converter=` and WPF doesn't give any indication that the binding failed.

My question is now: Is there a possibility to force WPF to always a apply a converter to specific types of bindings? Or, alternatively, how can I get WPF to give me proper errors when a Command binding fails?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can without either sub-classing Button (you probably don't want to do this), or defining your own attached property and using a TypeConverter attribute on it.

If you want to go with using a default converter via the TypeConverter attribute on a new attached property, you can look at Rob Relyea's informative post [here](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rob_relyea/archive/2008/04/10/strings-to-things-or-how-xaml-interprets-attribute-values.aspx), or MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970913.aspx).

Comment: From the first post it looks as if there is no need for the property to be an *attached* property. Anyways, I'll try it out and report back!

Comment: Actually, TypeConverters only seem to be used to convert from (XAML-)strings to actual property values. Bummer.

Answer (score 2):

While I've never done it, would it be possible to define a custom Markup Extension? That should cause the value to be sent to your class that implements the Markup Extension, and then from there you can return an `ICommand` that the `Command` property is expecting.

As I said, I've never created one my self, but a [Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?q=wpf+create+markup+extension) seems to bring up a few articles on how to do it.

Comment: Interesting idea. Though that only moves the problem from having to remember to use the converter to having to remember to use the custom markup extension.

Comment: True, but hopefully the syntax for the markup extension would be smaller than what you posted above - a small gain, if nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Check the debug output window. Normally you get to see the binding errors there.